# Multipeer connectivity - Advertise ViewController & browser ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multipeer-connectivity

**Problem**

I managed to get this to work following a tutorial and could successfully transfer data between the devices. However, I'm now trying to implement this into my application.

The problem is, it does not advertise in my `HostViewController`.

I'm probably missing something incredibly easy, however I cannot find the issue.

HostViewController ~ Advertiser.

```
#import "HostViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface HostViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;

@end

@implementation HostViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [_matchName setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)createMatchup:(id)sender {

    _appDelegate.mcManager.peerID = nil;
    _appDelegate.mcManager.session = nil;
    _appDelegate.mcManager.browser = nil;
    _appDelegate.mcManager.advertiser = nil;

    [_appDelegate.mcManager.advertiser stop];

    [_appDelegate.mcManager setupPeerAndSessionWithDisplayName:_matchName.text];
    [_appDelegate.mcManager setupMCBrowser];
    [_appDelegate.mcManager advertiseSelf:true];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [_matchName resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
@end
```

ConnectionViewController ~ leads to browser.

```
#import "ConnectionsViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LobbyViewController.h"

@interface ConnectionsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;

@end

@implementation ConnectionsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[_appDelegate mcManager] setupPeerAndSessionWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];
    [[_appDelegate mcManager] advertiseSelf:false];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)browseForDevices:(id)sender {
    [[_appDelegate mcManager] setupMCBrowser];
    [[[_appDelegate mcManager] browser] setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:[[_appDelegate mcManager] browser] animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)browserViewControllerDidFinish:(MCBrowserViewController *)browserViewController{
    [_appDelegate.mcManager.browser dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    //Here go to match lobby.
    LobbyViewController *lobby = [[LobbyViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:lobby animated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void)browserViewControllerWasCancelled:(MCBrowserViewController *)browserViewController{
    [_appDelegate.mcManager.browser dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

And finally, the;

MCManager ~ handles events

```
@implementation MCManager

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _peerID = nil;
        _session = nil;
        _browser = nil;
        _advertiser = nil;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)setupPeerAndSessionWithDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName{
    _peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:displayName];

    _session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID];
    _session.delegate = self;
}

-(void)setupMCBrowser{
    _browser = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat-files" session:_session];
}

-(void)advertiseSelf:(BOOL)shouldAdvertise{
    if (shouldAdvertise) {
        _advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat-files"
                                                           discoveryInfo:nil
                                                                 session:_session];
        [_advertiser start];
    }
    else{
        [_advertiser stop];
        _advertiser = nil;
    }
}

-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{

}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{

}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress{

}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID atURL:(NSURL *)localURL withError:(NSError *)error{

}


-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveStream:(NSInputStream *)stream withName:(NSString *)streamName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID{

}

@end
```

Host viewcontroller is `@interface HostViewController : UIViewController <MCAdvertiserAssistantDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>`

Connection ViewControiller is `@interface ConnectionsViewController : UIViewController <MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate>`

Yet, I cannot see the device/matchup name after `-(IBAction)createMatchup:(id)sender` has ran.

**Summary**

The device / matchup name does not show for the browsing device after `createMatchup` has ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
....
    _appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

in the viewdidload of **HostViewController.**

Knew it was something small =[